# I need to find the largest sum from a group of orders using LINQ and XML

Tags: xml, linq, join

I have joined together two collections from an XML file containing information regarding orders at a restaurant and their order numbers, which items are in those orders, and how much each item costs. I need to find which order is the most expensive and which is the least expensive using LINQ operations. I have gotten to the point where I have a joined collection, but I'm not sure how I would sum up each order individually then find which costs the most / least.

Here's what I have so far for this part:

```
private void Question3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItems = doc
            .Root
            .Element("menuItems")
            .Elements("menuItem")
            .Select(s => new
            {
                itemNr = s.Attribute("nr"),
                itemPrice = double.Parse(s.Attribute("price").Value, NumberStyles.Currency),
                name = s.Value
            });

        var orders = doc
            .Root
            .Element("orders")
            .Elements("order")
            .Select(r => new
            {
                itemNr = r.Attribute("nr")
            });

        var joinedList = menuItems
            .Join(orders,
            menuItem => menuItem.itemNr,
            order => order.itemNr,
            (menuItem, order) => new
            {
                orderNr = order.itemNr,
                itemNr = menuItem.itemNr,
                itemPrice = menuItem.itemPrice
            });

            //.Sum(order => order.itemPrice);

        AnswerBox.Text = joinedList.ToString();
    }
```

EDIT: This is what I have now, and I'm getting "Sequence contains no elements"

```
private void Question3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItems = doc
            .Root
            .Element("menuItems")
            .Elements("menuItem")
            .Select(s => new
            {
                itemNr = s.Attribute("nr"),
                itemPrice = double.Parse(s.Attribute("price").Value, NumberStyles.Currency),
                name = s.Value
            });

        var orders = doc
            .Root
            .Element("orders")
            .Elements("order")
            .Select(r => new
            {
                orderNr = r.Attribute("nr")
            });

        var joinedList = menuItems
            .Join(orders,
            menuItem => menuItem.itemNr,
            order => order.orderNr,
            (menuItem, order) => new
            {
                orderNr = order.orderNr,
                itemNr = menuItem.itemNr,
                itemPrice = menuItem.itemPrice
            }).GroupBy(order => order.itemNr)
            .Select(g => new
                {
                    orderNr = g.Key,
                    Sum = g.Sum(list => list.itemPrice)
                })
                    .Max(g => g.Sum);

        //var least = joinedList.Min(list => list.itemPrice);

        AnswerBox.Text = joinedList.ToString();
    }
```

the XML:


  
    B.L.T. 
    Bacon Cheeseburger
    Baklava
    Chef Salad
    Chicken Filet
    Chicken Fried Steak
    Chicken Kabob
    Chili Burger
    Chili Dog
    Cold Turkey
    Corn Dog
    Dinner Salad
    Double Bacon Cheeseburger
    Double Burger
    Double Cheeseburger
    Double Royal Burger
    Fish Filet
    Greek Salad
    Grilled Cheese
    Grilled Ham and Cheese
    Gyro
    Gyro Dinner (Salad and Fries)
    Hot Dog
    Junior Bacon Cheese
    Junior Burger
    Junior Cheeseburger
    Junior Royal (Pastrami)
    Muffins
    Mushroom Swiss Burger
    Onion Rings
    Pastrami Melt
    Patty Melt
    Quarter Burger
    Quarter Burger w/ Cheese
    Royal Burger (Pastrami)
    Smothered Chili Cheeseburger
    Steak Fries
    Tuna Melt
    Tuna Salad
    Tuna Sandwich

Comment: How would you identify each order? You need the order number or id, so then you can summarize by order number/id

Comment: each order has an order number which is "nr" in the XML file.

Comment: Is it possible to paste your xml also?

Comment: I tried posting it but all it does is post all of the names of each element..

Answer (score 0):

Does this code help?

```
var grouping = from list in joinedList
           group list by list.orderNr into g
           select new { OrderNr = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(list => list.itemPrice) };
var most = grouping.Max(g => g.Sum);
var least = grouping.Min(g => g.Sum);
```

EDIT (Explanation)
You group your list by OrderNr first. So you will have a list of orderNumbers (g.key) and the Totol price of the order.

```
OrderNr | Sum
--------------
123     | 20
345     | 48
222     | 50
```

most will return OrderNr = 222, Sum = 50

least will return OrderNr = 123, Sum = 20

Comment: the code makes sense, but when I try to implement it in my own code, I get an 'InvalidOperationException was unhandled' error. "Sequence contains no elements"